# Why APIPA doesn't work with multiple network adapters?

Tags: networking, ip, dhcp

I connected 3 cameras to 3 network adapters in my PC. I don't have DHCHP, so I thought APIPA will do the work. But, camera's installation guide says "If a PC is equipped with multiple network adapters, APIPA can only be used on one of the adapters. If APIPA is enabled on more than one adapter, the network will not operate properly."

I've read about APIPA and that it has private IP range and 255.255.0.0 subnet mask, but I still don't understand why it doesn't work if each camera gets unique IP address from APIPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the OS won't know which adapter (aka interface) it should use to reach a given address.

Remember that APIPA always uses the *same* IP range, `169.254.0.0/16`, so your computer will have three adapters that have addresses in the exact same network.

---

On IPv6 (which makes APIPA-style automatic addresses mandatory), this problem is solved by using explicit *zone indexes* (most operating systems use adapter names or numbers for them). For example, trying to access `fe80::4a5:60f:fe8:58f%wlan0` will tell the OS to use the `wlan0` adapter, even though *all* of them are automatically assigned addresses in the `fe80::/64` range.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the basic but once OS found 3 adapters why it cannot now choose one of them? (I read relavent topics in tcp/ip but still didn't understand)

Comment: @theateist: That's exactly what it does – it chooses one adapter. Which means you cannot access the cameras connected to the other two.  Remember how subnets and routing tables work. The OS doesn't know which *specific* addresses can be reached over which adapter; it only has three subnet routes: "169.254.0.0/16 can be reached over adapter A", "169.254.0.0/16 can be reached over adapter B", and "169.254.0.0/16 can be reached over adapter C". So it can only choose one adapter for all APIPA addresses.

Comment: Maybe he can edit the routing tables manually to specify /32 routes... bbut that's against the "automatic" condition...

Answer (score 1):

You could connect all three cameras to a switch then that switch to a single network adapter and your computer should be able to communicate with all three. You don't need an interface per camera.